# Drop down options in payment button

Tags: paypal, download

I am adding paypal payment button to my web site. And I require to have drop down menu with list of selectable dates. Pay pal offers only 10 selectable options for drop down menu. I require approx 15 options. Can someone help me to add extra options please.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would create 2 buttons and split the options between the 2.